# How to trigger an event when any jQuery UI dialog is closed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I would like to make it so that when a jQuery UI dialog is closed, the document's `focus` event is fired. This would preferably not be tied to each dialog but to the page itself whenever any dialog closes.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you talking about a jQuery-UI dialog?

Comment: So then please have a look on experimentX' answer. It's exactly what your looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   close: function(event, ui) { $('#txt').focus(); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked [this](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-close)

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   close: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#image_div").dialog({
      height:500,
      width:600,
      maxHeight: 700,
      minWidth: 700,
      modal: true,
      title:'Crop Your Profile Image',
      close: function() {  
        //your event
      },
      buttons : {...}
  });
```